# NOT IN function in pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm trying to find out the difference between two tables(Source and Destination) using DIFF() method in pig, in order to achieve that:

```
sourcenew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Source.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:chararray,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);


destnew = LOAD 'hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/DVTTest/Destination.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (ID:chararray,Name:chararray,FirstName:chararray ,LastName:chararray,Vertical_Name:chararray ,Vertical_ID:chararray,Gender:chararray,DOB:chararray,Degree_Percentage:chararray ,Salary:chararray,StateName:chararray);

cogroupnew= COGROUP sourcenew by ID inner, destnew by ID inner;

diffnew = FOREACH cogroupnew GENERATE DIFF(sourcenew,destnew);

DUMP diffnew;
```

Gives the differences between two tables or return empty bag{} if tuples matches, it works fine until this, my next step is to find the extra records in source files which is not there in destination, for that

```
cogroupextrainsource= COGROUP sourcenew by ID inner, destnew by ID;
filterextrainsource= FILTER cogroupextrainsource BY ID NOT (cogroupnew)
```

its throwing error as expected.
Need help to find extra in source.
Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the $ sign next to the column name ID.$ is used only when you do not want to access the column by the name.

```
cogroupextrainsource = COGROUP sourcenew by ID inner, destnew by ID;
```